# How to Play/Stop background music and sound effects?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer

I have 2 sound effects and i can't stop them , however my background music works perfect.

My sound effects are in a different class - They Are in GameScene I run them from there.

How i can stop my sound effects correct?

**For example:** i have CatchObjectSound and i created the functions that i need. but still i can hear the sound effect when I'm clicking on the button.

---

**What i want to do?**

I want to stop my sound effects.

**SKTAudio Class :**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

public class Singleton {


    // Initialize
     public var backgroundMusicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
     public var soundEffectCatchObject: AVAudioPlayer?
     //public var soundEffectGameOver: AVAudioPlayer?
     //public var soundEffectClickedButton: AVAudioPlayer?



    public class func sharedInstance() -> Singleton {
        return SingletonInstance
    }


    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Play Background Music
    // ---------------------------------------------

    func playBackgroundMusic() {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Unity.mp3", withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find file: \("Unity.mp3")")
            return
        }
        do {
            backgroundMusicPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            backgroundMusicPlayer!.numberOfLoops = -1
            backgroundMusicPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
            backgroundMusicPlayer!.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }

    func pauseBackgroundMusic() {
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.pause()
    }

    func resumeBackgroundMusic() {
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.play()
    }


    // ---------------------------------------------
    // Play Sound Effect Catch Object
    // ---------------------------------------------

    func playSoundEffectCatchObject() {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Magical Echo Spell 03.wav", withExtension: nil)
        guard let newURL = url else {
            print("Could not find file: \("Magical Echo Spell 03.wav")")
            return
        }
        do {
            let error: NSError? = nil
            soundEffectCatchObject = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: newURL)
            if let player = soundEffectCatchObject {
            player.numberOfLoops = 0
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            } else {
            print("Could not create audio player: \(error!)")
        }
    }

    func pauseSoundEffectCatchObject() {
        if let player = soundEffectCatchObject {
        if player.playing {
           player.pause()
        }
    }
}

    func resumeSoundEffectCatchObject() {
        if let player = soundEffectCatchObject {
            if player.playing {
               player.play()
    }
            }
        }
    }
}

let SingletonInstance = Singleton()
```

I have button that pause/resume in main scene. 
the button works perfectly , but i can't stop my sound effect, i tried.

**Main Scene**

```
if(SoundOnOff.containsPoint(location)) {

            if  (Singleton.sharedInstance().backgroundMusicPlayer?.playing == true) {
                Singleton.sharedInstance().pauseBackgroundMusic()
               Singleton.sharedInstance().pauseSoundEffectCatchObject()
                self.SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"MusicOff.png")

            } else {
               Singleton.sharedInstance().resumeBackgroundMusic()
               Singleton.sharedInstance().resumeSoundEffectCatchObject()
                self.SoundOnOff.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"MusicOn.png")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So create a sound playing singleton. Give it methods to start and stop the 2 sound effects. Since it's a singleton you can call it from anywhere in your program.

Comment: I can't mute my sound effects

Comment: AVAudioPlayer doesn't have a mute function that I am aware of, but you can pause or stop it easily enough. What problem are you having?

Comment: My problem now in my if statement.

Comment: Dude, you need to learn to provide enough information. What does "My problem now in my if statement" mean? Have you tried stepping through your code in the debugger to see what's happening?